# autocomplete and the missing value default state in HTML forms

Tags: html, autocomplete

I am trying to understand the autocomplete attribute for HTML forms and form elements. I went through [W3C Specification of autocomplete](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-autocomplete-attribute) and [W3C Specification for enumerated attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/common-microsyntaxes.html#enumerated-attribute) and [A summary of the above two links](https://code.google.com/p/doctype-mirror/wiki/InputAutocompleteAttribute)

Now form what I understand W3C says: -

> The autocomplete attribute is an enumerated attribute. The attribute has three states. The on keyword maps to the on state, and the off keyword maps to the off state. **The attribute may also be omitted. The missing value default is the default state**.

So the above means that: -

Like when the autocomplete="on" is used, it means that autocomplete takes the **on** state - meaning autocomplete of the element is allowed.

Similarly, when the autocomplete="off" is used, it means that autocomplete takes the **off** state - meaning autocomplete of the element is not allowed.

Now, if the autocomplete attribute is missed out completely then the autocomplete takes the **missing value default** state.

Now what i do not understand here is this: -

The **on** state means that - autocomplete of the element is allowed, because that is what is defined for the **on** state. 
The **off** state means that - autocomplete of the element is not allowed, because that is what is defined for the **off** state. 
So similarly, what is meant by the **missing value default** state. What is defined for this state ?

Comment: Note that you are linking to a several years old Working Draft of W3C’s [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/). The [current draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-html5-20140617/) is from last month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase "missing value default" refers to the value that is assigned to the attribute when it's omitted from the element completely. "The missing value default is the default state" in other words is saying "When the attribute isn't specified, its state is 'default'".

So when you say

> Now, if the autocomplete attribute is missed out completely then the autocomplete takes the missing value default state.

you have it the wrong way around: When the attribute is missed out completely it takes the "default" state.

And the default state is defined later in the document:

> The default state indicates that the user agent is to use the autocomplete attribute on the element's form owner instead. (By default, the autocomplete attribute of form elements is in the on state.)

Comment: thanks and just to close the discussion.. so basically, if the autocomplete attribute (and am referring to the attribute itself and not its value) is not specified at all in the form, then by default, it is considered to be in the "on" state, that is auto complete is enabled, right ?

Comment: Yes. Well, "autocomplete allowed" would be even more accurate.